# getting TLE in leetcode question 212- word search 2 using backtrcaking even after pruning, how do i optimize it more

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, backtracking

***Question***

> Given an `m x n` board of characters and a list of strings words, return all words on the board.
>
> Each word must be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent cells, where adjacent cells are horizontally or vertically neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once in a word.

***Constraints:***

- `m == board.length`
- `n == board[i].length`
- `1 <= m, n <= 12`
- `board[i][j]` is a lowercase English letter.
- `1 <= words.length <= 3 * 10^4`
- `1 <= words[i].length <= 10`
- `words[i]` consists of lowercase English letters.
- All the strings of words are unique.

***Example:***

> Input: board = [["o","a","a","n"],["e","t","a","e"],["i","h","k","r"],["i","f","l","v"]], words = ["oath","pea","eat","rain"]
> Output: ["eat","oath"]

```
class Solution {
private:
    bool safe(int i, int j, vector<vector<bool>> &vis) {
        return (i >= 0 && i < vis.size() && j >= 0 && j < vis[0].size() && !vis[i][j]);
    }
    void solve(vector<string> &ans, vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<vector<bool>> &vis, string &s,
    int row, int col, int idx, int &flag){
        if (!safe(row, col, vis) || board[row][col] != s[idx])
            return;
        if(idx+1==s.size()){
            flag=1;
            ans.push_back(s);
            return;
        }

        vis[row][col] = true;
        solve(ans, board,vis, s, row + 1, col, idx + 1,flag); 
        vis[row][col] = false; 
        if(flag==1) return;

        vis[row][col] = true; 
        solve(ans, board,vis, s, row - 1, col, idx + 1,flag); 
        vis[row][col] = false;
        if(flag==1) return;

        vis[row][col] = true; 
        solve(ans, board,vis, s, row, col + 1, idx + 1,flag); 
        vis[row][col] = false;
        if(flag==1) return;

        vis[row][col] = true; 
        solve(ans, board,vis, s, row, col - 1, idx + 1,flag); 
        vis[row][col] = false;
        if(flag==1) return;

        return;
    }
public:
    vector<string> findWords(vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<string>& words) {
        vector<string> ans;
        vector<vector<bool>> vis(board.size(),vector<bool>(board[0].size(),0));
        for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
            int flag=0;
            for(int j=0;j<board.size();j++){
                for(int k=0;k<board[0].size();k++){
                    solve(ans,board,vis,words[i],j,k,0,flag);
                    if(flag==1) break;
                }
                if(flag==1) break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

I am doing this question using **backtracking** as specified by the tag of the question. Although my code is giving correct answer , it is giving **TLE** for very large input.
I have tried optimizing the code as much as i could. So i need your help further optimizing the same approach.

Comment: In plain English, what's the logic of your code?

Comment: Often a TLE means you need to use a different algorithm.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a strange beast. It is small but slow due to only using one bit per element, and very rarely used in the real world.

Comment: the tag of question says it can be done by backtracking, so that's why i am using that

Comment: Instead of doing a search for each word in the dictionary, look at each path on the board see if it's a word (creating paths using backtracking). You can terminate searches early if the prefix of the path you've found so far is not the prefix of any word in the dictionary.

Comment: Logic of my code:  i take one string from the vector of string and check if it exists, to do so i start one by one from every index and check if combined with adjacent cells it forms the words or not, if the word is found i do not check it from other indexes as it will give duplicate answers, that's the code i have implemented in the main function. In the solve function, first i prune if the current string will not contribute to the answer to avoid unnecessary calls, if the string is found i add it to the answer else i check all the adjacent cells and if string matches from any cell, i return.

Comment: I think you could benefit from reading about the trie structure.

Comment: Then try the opposite indeed (suggestion by @PaulHankin): browse through the cells and see if you form any word. If not, backtrack to the last cell where you could have gone a different path and take that path. It is hard (at least for me) to see what approach would be faster (or it could be a completely different one) but my guess is that, as you can sort words from the list, you most likely can test many words at once for each new cell you visit.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks the useful information, i tried using int instead of bool but it is still giving tle, maybe i'll have to change the whole logic

Comment: Cont'd: From you example, you know that no word starts with e.g. `a`. When trying to build a word that starts with `a`, the above suggestion would allow you to do a big shortcut: My first word is `eat` -> **no need to test the other words** (that would be a waste of time), I can backtrack immediately.

Comment: thank you guys, i'll try implementing it with the other approach or with trie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert all the given words into a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and only continue searching along a path while the current string is a prefix of some word in the trie.

Sample implementation (based on your code, with some modifications):

```cpp
struct TrieNode {
    TrieNode* children[26]{};
    bool wordEnd, found;
    ~TrieNode() {
        for (auto n : children) delete n;
    }
} *root;
void insert(const string& s) {
    auto curr = root;
    for (char c : s) {
        c -= 'a';
        if (!curr->children[c]) curr->children[c] = new TrieNode();
        curr = curr->children[c];
    }
    curr->wordEnd = true;
}
class Solution {
private:
    bool safe(int i, int j, vector<vector<bool>> &vis) {
        return i >= 0 && i < vis.size() && j >= 0 && j < vis[0].size() && !vis[i][j];
    }
    void solve(vector<string> &ans, vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<vector<bool>> &vis, string& s, TrieNode* node, int row, int col){
        if (!safe(row, col, vis) || !(node = node->children[board[row][col] - 'a'])) return;
        s += board[row][col];
        if (node->wordEnd && !node->found) node->found = true, ans.push_back(s);
        vis[row][col] = true;
        solve(ans, board, vis, s, node, row + 1, col); 
        solve(ans, board, vis, s, node, row - 1, col); 
        solve(ans, board, vis, s, node, row, col + 1); 
        solve(ans, board, vis, s, node, row, col - 1); 
        vis[row][col] = false;
        s.pop_back();
    }
public:
    vector<string> findWords(vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<string>& words) {
        root = new TrieNode();
        for (const auto& word : words) insert(word);
        vector<vector<bool>> vis(board.size(),vector<bool>(board[0].size(),0));
        string curr;
        vector<string> ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++) {
                solve(ans, board, vis, curr, root, i, j);
            }
        }
        delete root;
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Note that there is a faster trie implementation that does not perform dynamic memory allocation (using the problem constraints instead), but it is not necessary for this problem and tends to be harder to read.

Comment: Hello, I'm Leak, Memory Leak.

Comment: That's true, but it's still a memory leak. SO is not LeetCode, we care about quality of answers here.

Comment: @evg i am a student trying my best to learn , and here you are discouraging people like me, thanks man, i give more attention to it after i have learned basic algorithms

Comment: @Evg I've updated the solution in any case.

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but it's still wrong. Doing `TrieNode node;` is likely to crash your program. It's also weird that `TrieNode` calls `delete` on something that was not newed by `TrieNode`.

Comment: @Evg It doesn't happen in this program, but sure, `children` can be zero initialized (updated). For the other point, where else would `delete` be called? It certainly can't be called in `insert`.

Comment: Why do you need `new` and `delete` to begin with? In C++ you almost never use them. Why not to use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>`?

Comment: A hashset of prefixes (using string_view rather than string if the dict size or average word length is large) is a lot simpler than using a trie.